# Reminder chatbot for facebook messenger

Tags: c#, botframework

Hi i am trying to make a reminder bot for facebook messenger. i found this sample on github for Teams and tried it on bot emulator but did not work. In the createConversation there is a TeamsChannelData, how can i change it to to work for facebook messenger? any help would be appreaciated thank you.

```
namespace ProactiveTeamsBot
{
    public class ProactiveBot : ActivityHandler
    {
        double _secondsToReply = 3;
        ICredentialProvider _credentialProvider;

        public ProactiveBot(ICredentialProvider credentialProvider)
        {
            _credentialProvider = credentialProvider;
        }

        protected override async Task OnMessageActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            try
            {
                await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text($"I'll reply to you in {_secondsToReply} seconds."));
                QueueReplyAndSendItProactively(turnContext).Wait();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
                throw e;
            }
        }

        public async Task QueueReplyAndSendItProactively(ITurnContext turnContext)
        {
            string conversationMessage = "I created my own conversation.";
            string replyMessage = "I proactively replied to this conversation.";

            var task = Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(_secondsToReply));

                var response = await CreateConversation(conversationMessage, turnContext);

                await ProactivelyReplyToConversation(response.Id, replyMessage, turnContext);

                return Task.CompletedTask;
            });
            await task;
        }

        public async Task<ConversationResourceResponse> CreateConversation(string message, ITurnContext turnContext )
        {
            ConnectorClient _client = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(turnContext.Activity.ServiceUrl), await GetMicrosoftAppCredentialsAsync(turnContext), new HttpClient());
            var channelData = turnContext.Activity.GetChannelData<TeamsChannelData>();

            var conversationParameter = new ConversationParameters
            {
                Bot = turnContext.Activity.Recipient,
                IsGroup = true,
                ChannelData = channelData,
                TenantId = channelData.Tenant.Id,
                Activity = MessageFactory.Text(message)
            };
            var response = await _client.Conversations.CreateConversationAsync(conversationParameter);
            return response;
        }

        public async Task ProactivelyReplyToConversation(string conversationId, string message, ITurnContext turnContext)
        {
            ConnectorClient _client = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(turnContext.Activity.ServiceUrl), await GetMicrosoftAppCredentialsAsync(turnContext), new HttpClient());
            var reply = MessageFactory.Text(message);
            reply.Conversation = new ConversationAccount(isGroup: true, id: conversationId);
            await _client.Conversations.SendToConversationAsync(reply);
        }

        private async Task<MicrosoftAppCredentials> GetMicrosoftAppCredentialsAsync(ITurnContext turnContext)
        {
            ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = turnContext.TurnState.Get<ClaimsIdentity>("BotIdentity");

            Claim botAppIdClaim = claimsIdentity.Claims?.SingleOrDefault(claim => claim.Type == AuthenticationConstants.AudienceClaim)
                ??
                claimsIdentity.Claims?.SingleOrDefault(claim => claim.Type == AuthenticationConstants.AppIdClaim);

            string appPassword = await _credentialProvider.GetAppPasswordAsync(botAppIdClaim.Value).ConfigureAwait(false);
            return new MicrosoftAppCredentials(botAppIdClaim.Value, appPassword);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you're trying to do, you just want to send a message after a period of time and don't actually want to create a new conversation. This means your task is far simpler than the sample you've provided. Your `QueueReplyAndSendItProactively` method could look like this:

```
public async Task QueueReplyAndSendItProactively(ITurnContext turnContext)
{
    var task = Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(_secondsToReply));
        await turnContext.SendActivityAsync("I proactively replied to this conversation.");
    });

    await task;
}
```

Note that some will consider it bad practice to manage your timer functionality within the bot itself because of scalability issues etc., but it's the simplest way to do this.

Comment: Can the conversation continue with this Sir Kyle? If possible i want the bot to send a reminder and when the user is in a middle of a dialog the dialog will still continue. The reminders will be in weeks or 1 month (Bills payments) and what i am planning to do is create a loop that will check database everyday and if date matches, the bot will send a proactive message to the user.

Comment: Okay that is far more complicated and difficult than the question you asked. On a large scale like that, it is a very bad idea to have your timers running in the bot code. You might want an Azure Function or something like that. Do you want to ask a new question that explains how you've set up a scheduled task that regularly check the database?

Comment: Can i ask it and send you the link sir kyle? Or a task that posts to an API when the date matches a date.

Comment: @user10860402 - My team will see any question you tag with "botframework"